# bytea in postgres not correctly escaped?

Tags: postgresql, bytea

I have problems with copying bytea data in trigger from one table to another.

The original query looks like:

```
INSERT INTO "mytable" ("dataid","data")
VALUES 
(123456,'\x3008d1a10a000000050000000000000000000000fb27000009090504010804060a08020b020c040000000000000000000000000001000000'::bytea);
```

Inside "before insert" trigger, I get syntax error when trying to insert this value to another table. The reason is that inside the trigger the value NEW.data is already escaped and looks like

```
0\010\321\241\012\000\000\000\005\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\373\'000\000\011\011\005\004\001\010\004\006\012\010\002\013\002\014\004\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\001\000\000\000
```

Is there a way to retrive  NEW.dataid actual value  ( before type cast or as a string ) ?

p.s. I cannot change original query or convert or set bytea_output to hex on production db

Trigger function code:

```
BEGIN 
PERFORM dblink('logsyellow', '
    INSERT INTO datastorage(dataid,data)    
    VALUES(' || new.dataid || ','||new.data||') 
');
RETURN new;
END;
```

Error I get:

```
PL/pgSQL function fn_replicate_data() line 4 at PERFORM
2014-07-08 13:24:35 GMT OPERATOR:  INSERT INTO mytable ( dataid, data ) VALUES ( 123456, '\x3008d1a10a000000050000000000000000000000fb27000009090504010804060a08020b020c040000000000000000000000000001000000'::bytea );
2014-07-08 13:24:35 GMT ERROR:  syntax error (at near "\")
2014-07-08 13:24:35 GMT CONTEXT:  Error occurred on dblink connection named "unnamed": could not execute command.
        SQL-operator: "SELECT DBLINK_EXEC('logsyellow','INSERT INTO datastorage(dataid,data)        VALUES('||new.dataid||','''||new.data||''') ')"
```

Comment: There's nothing special to do, since a bytea column in `NEW` in a trigger is actually **not escaped**. Please show the code and error message or reproducible test case that makes you think otherwise.

Comment: Hi Daniel, just added function code and error above. The reason I think it is already **escaped**, because "raise notice" + sql query shows  INSERT INTO datastorage ( dataid, data ) VALUES(123456,0\010\321\241\012\000\000\000\005\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\373\'000\000\011\011\005\004\001\010\004\006\012\010\002\013\002\014\004\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\001\000\000\000);

Comment: @Natalie It gets escaped as part of formatting into a string for display.

Comment: @Craig it gets escaped on the stage of building dblink query or before, otherwise I wouldn't get syntax error. Original query is correct and doesn't produce errors.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got a solution.. thanks to everyone)

```
PERFORM dblink('logsyellow','INSERT INTO datastorage(dataid,data)   VALUES(' || new.dataid || ','||quote_literal(new.data)||') ')
```